# When i click on edit give me inputfield and 2 buttons

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
 <div class="fa fa-edit clickable edit-icon" (click)="editProject()"></div>
{{project.name}}
```

This is the code I want, when I click on this icon, the `project.name` needs to turn into an input field and give me 2 buttons in the same page

I am working with html and typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngIf` and a property binding

In your component's class:

```
public isInputVisible : boolean = false;
public editProject(): void {
   this.isInputVisible = true;
}
```

In your template:

```
<div class="fa fa-edit clickable edit-icon" (click)="editProject()"></div>
<ng-container *ngIf="!isInputVisible">{{project.name}}</ng-container>
<input [(ngModel)]=project.name"" *ngIf="isInputVisible" />
```

Comment: Thank u, but im having some problems.
this is connect with store, name of project comes from my dialog, when i applied your code to html and to component.ts
Declaration of instance field not allowed after declaration of instance method. Instead, this should come at the beginning of the class/interface. (member-ordering).
'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: This is a tslint error related to the styling of your code, not the actual correctness, but I may be able to help if you post your complete code .